# Struct property operator overload

Tags: c++, struct, properties

I'm writing a game in C++ for my Arduino and I've recently found the joys of operator overloading in structs.  So far so good!  I'm now stuck on the syntax to overload operators on properties.  I want to implement something like this so that if my x or y values increase over the screen width I wrap the value back to 0.  Many thanks!

```
// My guess :(
x& operator++(x &newx, int){
    if (x == SCREEN_WIDTH - 1)
        return 0;
    else
        return x + 1;
}
```

My struct definition is:

```
struct point_t
{
    uint8_t x;
    uint8_t y;
    x& operator++(x &newx, int){
        if (x == SCREEN_WIDTH - 1)
            return 0;
        else
            return x + 1;
    }
    point_t& operator=(const point_t &p)
    {
        x = p.x;
        y = p.y;
        return *this;
    }
    bool operator==(const point_t &p) const
    {
        return (x == p.x && y == p.y);
    }
    bool operator!=(const point_t &p) const
    {
        return !(x == p.x && y == p.y);
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you post what your calling code should look like for this? I don't quite understand how that operator should be used.

Comment: But `x` is not a type?

Comment: Hi!  Many thanks!  What I'm trying to do is call mypoint.x++ or mypoint.y++ and when the x or v is bigger than some max value the code in the operator automatically sets the value to 0 instead of incrementing

Comment: I want to overload the x++, x--, y++ and y-- properties of the struct so that I can maintain a suitable range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this exactly as written. The return type of operator should be *type*.

What you *can* do is to create a new type, say `coordinate`, overload `operator++` for it, and have your `x` (and `y`) have `coordinate` type, not `uint8_t`.

Possible solution (based on code by @MrMase):

```
template<uint8_t MAX>
class coordinate_t
{
    private:
        int8_t _p;
    public:
        coordinate_t(int8_t p = 0): _p(p) {}

        // Postfix ++
        coordinate_t operator++(int)  
        {
            coordinate_t p(_p);
            ++_p;
            if (_p > MAX - 1)
                _p = 0;
            return p;
        }

        // Postfix --
        coordinate_t operator--(int)  
        {
            coordinate_t p(_p);
            --_p;
            if (_p < 0)
                _p = MAX - 1;
            return p;
        }

        int get() const {return _p;}
};

typedef coordinate_t<SCREEN_WIDTH> xcoordinate_t;
typedef coordinate_t<SCREEN_HEIGHT> ycoordinate_t;
```

I've made it a template to allow for a simple `typedef` to define different coordinates; you might also have made `MAX` a private field and subclass it for different coordinates. In fact, it seems that the template solution is more safe, as it will not allow you to mix different coordinates; however, you might want to reconsider this based on your actual usage.

See full example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5a34261310d05a54

Comment: Hi!  Many thanks!  What I'm trying to do is call mypoint.x++ or mypoint.y++ and when the x or v is bigger than some max value the code in the operator automatically sets the value to 0 instead of incrementing

Comment: Hi, are you saying that it's not possible to overload a struct property?  In that the operator `mypoint.x++` cannot be done?  Thanks.

Comment: @MrMase, it can be done, but only provided `mypoint.x` is of a different type, not `uint8_t`.

Comment: @MrMase, thanks for the code example. Note that I have rewritten it; the new version seems more readable and safe to me. Even if the template implementation does not suit you, in your code I would make `max` a `private` member and set it via a constructor; also note the use of constructor initializer lists.

Answer (score 0):

When overloading unary operators (operators with only a single operand, like the increase/decrease operators `++` and `--`) as member functions, they don't have an argument since they are performed on `this`. The exceptions being the dummy `int` arguments for the postfix increase/decrease operators.

The returned value differs depending on which operator you overload, but generally for unary operator you return a reference to object, i.e. `*this`.

Example

```
struct point_t
{
    int x;

    // Prefix increase operator
    point_t& operator++()
    {
        ++x;
        return *this;
    }

    // Postfix increase operator
    point_t operator++(int)
    {
        point_t old(*this);  // Create new object using copy-constructor
        operator++();  // Call prefix operator++ on `this`
        return old;  // Return old value, before increment
    }

    ...
};
```

It's all documented in [this operator overloading reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators), as well as plenty of tutorials all over the Internet.

---

On an unrelated note, that `operator!=` can be implemented by using the `==` operator that you have already implemented:

```
bool operator!=(const point_t& p) const
{
    return !(*this == p);
}
```

It's always a good idea to use existing operators when creating related operator overloads.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I don't want to overload the operators of struct itself, I want to overloads <code>struct.x++ struct.x--  struct.y++ struct.y </code>  so I can handle change the value when it reaches a min or max

Comment: @MrMase Then that's not possible. You *could* to it if you create a wrapper-type for the coordinates. But the usual when modifying screen coordinates, is to have the check before increasing the coordinate, not part of the actual increment (just because it's usually more work, and it's much easier to have a special function to increase/decrease the coordinate which does the check).

Comment: The second tip about the `operator!=` is awesome!  Thanks for that!  I've learnt a lot!

Comment: in that case I have to scrap this idea then!  I do have coordinate range checking elsewhere.  Many thanks! :D :D

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's not possible to overload a property of an enum so I'm going to do the next best thing: create a new type called xcordinate and overload the ++operator

Thanks very much to everyone who helped.  I'm grateful! :)

Comment: Here is the final implementation

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f3a39aef4fe56c4